# Can't connect to MySQL running on host 'Name Cheap'

Tags: mysql, authentication, host, web-development-server

When trying to use my custom database with creating users in Auth O it prompts me with this auto generated code.

```javascript
function login(email, password, callback) {
    var connection = mysql({
        host: '', // What should I put for the host?
                  // Is it a ip address or just Name Cheap
        user: '',
        password: '',
        database: ''
    });
}
```

When I type in Name Cheap or any derivation of namecheap I receive this 
error:

> [Error] ENOTFOUND - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND Name Cheap Name Cheap:3306

What do I put in the host? many of the example use local host but I am using name cheap to host my website. Is there a number associated with Name Cheap or something? If so what is that called?

Comment: I have reformatted your post. Please review [Stack Overflow's formatting system](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and use appropriate formatting. Explanatory text should never be in a code block. I also updated your title to more accurately reflect the problem. Good titles are important for getting page views. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the `host` value should be (this will depend on the provider), but it isn't `"Name Cheap"`. That doesn't identify a machine or cluster.

It should be an IP address (which it sounds like you have) or a hostname. See the [MySQL documentation about connecting](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

in some reason.. you should put

> localhost

... and if you connect remotely.. you can put the host ip address:

> 216.58.199.110

or domain name

> myawesomewebsite.com

For Remote Access: in your Cpanel->MySQL Remote Access then add "%" allowing any IP to connect your mysql. You can also specify address like: your public IP.

if you have any plan to change Hosting.. you may try this: jumboNIC just in case.. https://www.jumbonic.com/cpanel-plans/